# OK to CNAME all DNS Records when moving hosts

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I am moving servers, and with that, going and updating all of the domains A records from the old IP addresses to the new ones. With around 100 domains this is a tedious process.

If I set a DNS record on the primary domain, eg server1.mydomain.com with IP address 1 of new server and server2.mydomian.com of the second new server, then CNAMED every domain to one of those, is that bad ?

This means if I move from this host, I can update one record and all sites will move over ?

Thanks

Comment: Dial down your TTLs before you move.  Otherwise clients will cache the old values for as long as your current TTL.

Comment: Thanks, what is a good Value ? I have 86400 by default

Comment: How long do you want the move to take?  86400 seconds is one day.

Comment: Remember that you *can't* cname ***every*** domain name. In particular you cannot cname the base domain name (`example.com`) because you already have an SOA record (and NS records) for it. There are also other record types (`MX`) which *must* point to an `A`ddress record per the RFCs...

Comment: Where is your DNS hosted?  If you have access to the server, just do a find and replace type of operation on the DNS zone file.

Answer (score 0):

What DNS server are both machines running? Microsoft? BIND?

There should be a way for you to automate migration, which would do the 100 domains for you.
Heck, you could even ask for access to do a domain transfer (AXFR) and get the domains that way.